# Audiomack embeds is not responsive on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have two WordPress blogs, which I'm not using the same Wordpress theme. I'm facing issue on the 2nd site, the problem is that Audiomack embeds doesn't fit the screen on mobile devices.

The 1st site embeds work perfectly on mobile devices. Link to the embeds [mr-eazi-one-day-you-will-understand-ep](https://six9ja.com/mr-eazi-one-day-you-will-understand-ep/).

On the 2nd site, all the embeds are responsive on mobile devices except Audiomack embeds. Link to the embeds [voice-kenchi-talkative](https://xclusiveloaded.com/voice-kenchi-talkative/).

The screenshot: [Picture of Audiomack embeds hides play and waves icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b579.png)

My CCS and HTML for responsive iframe:

```css
/*---------- Responive Iframes ---------*/
 @media (max-width:767px) {
  .iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}
 
.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
 
/* 4x3 Aspect Ratio */
.iframe-container-4x3 {
  padding-top: 75%;
}}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container"><iframe></iframe></div>
```

Comment: How about filling that `iframe` so we can see the issue in the code snippet.  Try to make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Links to your website will likely change and be useless to future StackOverflow users.

Comment: You have several problems with your code.  Stop using empty paragraphs for spacing `<p></p>`.  Instead use margins and padding.  Get rid of `height:100%`.  In your media queries for max-width 768px, get rid of `position:absolute` on your iframe and get rid of `padding-top: 56.25%` on the iframe container.  Then come back to us with a reproducible example if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing `padding-top: 56.25%` to `padding-top: 70%` on **iframe-container**.

I've checked Audiomack, Soundcloud, and YouTube embeds, everything works perfectly now.

**My reproducible CSS:**

```css
/*---------- Responive Iframes ---------*/
 @media (max-width:767px) {
  .iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 70%;
  position: relative;
}
 
.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

[My result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkVHD.png)